# Prove that $\mathbf{Nor}-N$ is a category.

Tags: category-theory

> I am doing Problem 1 in Appendix II (Category Theory) of Dummit and Foote, and I am a bit confused at one of the steps. I am new to Category Theory so please bear with me.

Let $N$ be a group and let $\mathbf{Nor}-N$ be the collection of all groups that contain $N$ as a normal subgroup. A morphism between objects $A$ and $B$ is any group homomorphism that maps $N$ into $N$.

(a) Prove that $\mathbf{Nor}-N$ is a category.

(b) Show how the projection homomorphism $G \mapsto G/N$ may be used to define a functor from $\mathbf{Nor}-N$ to $\mathbf{Grp}$.

> Regarding (a), part of the definition of a category in the book is that "If $A \neq C$ or $B \neq D$, then $Hom(A,B)$ and $Hom(C,D)$ are disjoint sets." I feel like this is trivial for if $A \neq C$, then clearly no function can just be in both sets as it can't have two domains. Even if $C\subseteq A$ or something like that, then a restriction wouldn't count either as it really isn't the "same" function. The case of $B \neq D$ would be similar but with the codomain. Thoughts?

Comment: What is sort of implicit in his definition is that for a category $C$ you have a set of objects $\mathrm{Ob}(C)$ and a set of morphisms $\mathrm{Mor}(C)$. Then $\mathrm{Hom}(A, B) \subset \mathrm{Mor}(C)$, and you should interpret disjointness in this context. As you have observed, these two sets are pretty much trivially disjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disjointness is there only for convenience purposes. You can always start from a category where hom-sets are not disjoint, and construct a category whose objects are the same, but each morphism $f:A\to B$ in the old category becomes $(A, f, B)$ in the new category. Then you just define composition in the new category as $(A, f, B) \circ (B, g, C) = (A, f\circ g, C)$. This creates an isomorphic (in a very strong sense) category that satisfies the disjointness property.

Comment: What would be an example of a category where the hom-sets are not disjoint for some $A \neq C$ or $B \neq D$?

Comment: @TheSenate Consider a category with four objects $A,B,C,D$ and 1 morphism $f$. Now impose that $f\circ f=f$. Insist that $f$ belongs to every hom-set.